# Google FIT Rest API Get automatic tracks

Tags: rest, api, google-fit

I try to get through the Google Fit REST API the automatic tracks stored by Google Fit on my android mobile. (for example : a bike session, start date, duration, activity type bike, walking...)

I simply tried the [session API](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/reference/users/sessions/list) :

```
GET /fitness/v1/users/me/sessions?startTime=2018-11-09T00:00:00.00Z&endTime=2018-11-09T23:59:59.99Z HTTP/1.1
```

but i get no result :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-length: 42
X-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
Content-location: https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/sessions?startTime=2018-11-09T00:00:00.00Z&endTime=2018-11-09T23:59:59.99Z
X-content-type-options: nosniff
Transfer-encoding: chunked
Expires: Fri, 09 Nov 2018 20:50:48 GMT
Vary: Origin, X-Origin
Server: GSE
Etag: "977qOFam2oE2uMtwc7J4i3egnsw/vyGp6PvFo4RvsFtPoIWeCReyIC8"
Cache-control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-transform
Date: Fri, 09 Nov 2018 20:50:48 GMT
X-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
Alt-svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="44,43,39,35"
Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
-content-encoding: gzip
{
  "deletedSession": [], 
  "session": []
}
```

I tried also to perform an [aggregate](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/reference/users/dataset/aggregate) :

```
POST /fitness/v1/users/me/dataset:aggregate HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-length: 281
Content-type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer XXXXXX
{
  "aggregateBy": [
    {
            "dataSourceId": "derived:com.google.activity.segment:com.google.android.gms:merge_activity_segments"

    }
  ],
  "bucketByActivityType": { "durationMillis": 86400000 }, 
  "startTimeMillis": 1541621627000,
  "endTimeMillis": 1541797627000
}
```

I got a result, but i don't find any way to decrypt that !

```
{
  "bucket": [
    {
      "activity": 1, 
      "dataset": [
        {
          "dataSourceId": "derived:com.google.activity.summary:com.google.android.gms:aggregated", 
          "point": [
            {
              "startTimeNanos": "1541662372620000000", 
              "originDataSourceId": "derived:com.google.activity.segment:com.google.android.gms:merge_activity_segments", 
              "endTimeNanos": "1541778156173000000", 
              "value": [
                {
                  "mapVal": [], 
                  "intVal": 1
                }, 
                {
                  "mapVal": [], 
                  "intVal": 6216497
                }, 
                {
                  "mapVal": [], 
                  "intVal": 6
                }
              ], 
              "dataTypeName": "com.google.activity.summary"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }, 
    {
      "activity": 3, 
      "dataset": [
        {
          "dataSourceId": "derived:com.google.activity.summary:com.google.android.gms:aggregated", 
          "point": [
            {
              "startTimeNanos": "1541621627000000000", 
              "originDataSourceId": "derived:com.google.activity.segment:com.google.android.gms:merge_activity_segments", 
              "endTimeNanos": "1541796648562000000", 
              "value": [
                {
                  "mapVal": [], 
                  "intVal": 3
                }, 
                {
                  "mapVal": [], 
                  "intVal": 163981252
                }, 
                {
                  "mapVal": [], 
                  "intVal": 11
                }
              ], 
              "dataTypeName": "com.google.activity.summary"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }, 
    {
      "activity": 7, 
      "dataset": [
        {
          "dataSourceId": "derived:com.google.activity.summary:com.google.android.gms:aggregated", 
          "point": [
            {
              "startTimeNanos": "1541667650063000000", 
              "originDataSourceId": "derived:com.google.activity.segment:com.google.android.gms:merge_activity_segments", 
              "endTimeNanos": "1541779218129000000", 
              "value": [
                {
                  "mapVal": [], 
                  "intVal": 7
                }, 
                {
                  "mapVal": [], 
                  "intVal": 3443813
                }, 
                {
                  "mapVal": [], 
                  "intVal": 13
                }
              ], 
              "dataTypeName": "com.google.activity.summary"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }, 
    {
      "activity": 58, 
      "dataset": [
        {
          "dataSourceId": "derived:com.google.activity.summary:com.google.android.gms:aggregated", 
          "point": [
            {
              "startTimeNanos": "1541792220000000000", 
              "originDataSourceId": "derived:com.google.activity.segment:com.google.android.gms:merge_activity_segments", 
              "endTimeNanos": "1541793600000000000", 
              "value": [
                {
                  "mapVal": [], 
                  "intVal": 58
                }, 
                {
                  "mapVal": [], 
                  "intVal": 1380000
                }, 
                {
                  "mapVal": [], 
                  "intVal": 1
                }
              ], 
              "dataTypeName": "com.google.activity.summary"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I am looking for any suggestion, it seems really strange to not see any use case like this on the google dev portal. At this stage I didn't see any mention that is not possible or not to realize this use case.

Comment: "I don't find any way to decrypt that" what do you mean by "decrypt"? Do you know what the three value fields (e.g. 1, 6216497, 6) mean? They are described [here](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/data-types) as showing you have 6 segments of cycling ([activity 1](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/reference/activity-types)), with total duration 6,216,497 milliseconds. (The first field in the value duplicates the "activity" field.)

Comment: Thank it is what i was looking for, how to map these values.